# DIfference between inline query in select clause and a join in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between:

```
select e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       e.id,
       d.dept_name
from employees e, departments d
where e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

and

```
select e.first_name,
       e.last_name,
       e.id,
       (select d.dept_name frpm departments d where d.department_id = e.department_id) dept_name    
from employees e;
```

I am talking about differences in performance, query time, CPU utilization etc.
Which one is better to use?

Comment: Why don't you tell us? Just test it and we can discuss our facts. No offense.

Comment: There has always been a Worst Case, Best Case scenario for both the queries.
You have to explore them by your own under varying conditions in database records.

Comment: The bottom one gives you the number of records in employee and an error if employee : department is not 1:1. The top one might give you more or less than the number of employees depending on how the match works. If you have your FK's set up this isn't a worry but be aware it's possible they don't give you the same results at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first one works as `inner join`; the returned rows are rows with matched ID in both tables.

While the second one will get you `NULL` in case there is no shared department ID in the sub select, but it will still give you the results of your main select